# Ubuntu Oracle Virtualbox problem in booting

Tags: boot, virtualbox, oracle

[image: (idk why image is not coming probably bcoz I'm new , please see it , it contains the screen , huge amounts of text and nothing makes sense to me , but looks like it's not booting properly )]

Hi, I'm trying to open ubuntu on oracle virtualbox after a long time and it seems to get stuck on this screen .
Things I have tried already :

- Reinstalling virtualbox .
- Changing(Increasing) number of processors from 1 to 2 and 3 .
- Enabling PAE/NX .
- Setting RAM to 4gb , 3gb, 1gb, 0.5gb .
- Setting paravirtualisation interface to default .
- Changing video memory from 16mb to 32mb .
- Changing graphics controller from VMSMGA to other options .
- Also restarting multiple times .
- Waiting for 3hrs doing nothing hoping that it's just slow in booting
  and will run later .

...

- Every solution available on internet .

Please tell me what to do to run it, I don't know much (or rather anything) about virtualisation , so please explain in simple terms what I have to do .
Thanks in advance .
First question on stack ubuntu , so ignore why I couldn't make bullet points .

EDIT- I left oracle VirtualBox and started using VMware,  so problem is solved at my end
Host is windows 10 , ram is 8 gb , Ubuntu is 18.04

Comment: The error message is about networking so every single thing you tried couldn't possibly fix it but may make it worse. Please check Virtualbox's network settings.

Comment: Which host system is it (the operating system where VirtualBox is running)? Windows or MacOS, and version of the operating system? Which version of VirtualBox? Which version of Ubuntu is it? What computer is it (brand name and model)? How much RAM is there in the computer? -- Please put the answers into you *original question*.

Comment: Did you check with `sha256sum` that the Ubuntu iso file was downloaded correctly?

Comment: You may want to change the Ubuntu flavor to MATE or Xubuntu.

Comment: If you wish, you can write a 'full answer' to your question, and after two days 'accept' it. That can help other users with the same problem.

Comment: because someone recently saw this and said they had the same problem.... The problem shown in the OP's picture has to do with loading the graphical desktop. (The other 'FAILED's came and went, they didn't stop progress) Moving from Virtualbox to Vmware should not have had to be the solution to solve this. It was most likely a driver issue... the next message in the log would be "Reached target Graphical Interface". The OP may have been able to log into the console via <RCTRL>+F3 and attempt to fix issues.